# How to find the true (case-sensitive) name of a file in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'm working with files on a case-insensitive (Mac/Windows) file system in C#.  But I'd like to find out the real (case-sensitive) name of this file as stored on disk.

I tried making a `new FileInfo(filePath)` and checking the FullName, but that just gives me back the path I gave it.  And the Name property just strips off the directory, again giving me the name as I passed it in, rather than the name of the file actually stored on disk.

I guess I could iterate over all the files in the parent directory, and look for one that best matches the file of interest, but that's going to kill performance.  Surely there's an API somewhere that will do this efficiently?

Comment: In case it helps, this thread suggests that the Windows C functions GetFilePath and GetLongPathName return the correct case as stored on disk in Windows: https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?470072-Determine-case-sensitive-(case-correct)-path-filename   So APIs exist for that on Windows at least.  I'm just looking for something in .NET that can do this cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

In my test this gives the name as written on disk

```
var x = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\temp", "TEST.EXE");
Console.WriteLine(x); // => outputs: E:\temp\test.exe
```

Comment: Will not this internally iterate over all files, which OP wanted to prevent?

Comment: Probably, but somewhere some kind of loop should exists. Unless we can access directly the underlying structure kept by the filesystem. I don't know if it is possible at high level code or even if exist any API for that. The code for the GetFiles method is published on the referencesource.com. I would like to look at it, but no time now.

Comment: Hmm.  For me, GetFiles appears to be the only file-related API I've found so far that *is* case sensitive.  It returns an empty array unless the file name specified as the search pattern matches the actual file in case.  (I probably should have specified that I'm using Unity, testing with both .NET 2.0 and 4.x.)

Comment: And yes, a quick browse of the reference source seems to indicate that this is iterating over all files in the directory, and potentially doing more complex processing (glob-matching) than I would need to do myself.